# DHTMLX Gantt. Проблема с родителем в методе gantt.createTask()

Tags: javascript

Помогите понять в чем проблема с методом gantt.createTask()

Создал свою пользовательскую форму по примеру https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/desktop__custom_edit_form.html

Создал свои кнопки по добавлению тасков:

```html
var newTaskTemplate = {
 id: "-1",
 person_name: "",
 state: ""
}

function createGanttTaskOnclick() {
 var id = gantt.getState().lightbox;
 if (id) {
  id = gantt.createTask(newTaskTemplate);
 }
}

function createGanttChieldTaskOnclick() {
 var parentId = gantt.getSelectedId();
 if (parentId) {
  gantt.createTask(newTaskTemplate, parentId)
 } else {
  messanger("Выберите родительский этап.");
 }
}
```

Выбираем на диаграмме родительский таск и нажимаем кнопку createGanttChieldTaskOnclick(). Все нормально новый таск становится подчиненным к выбранному.
Теперь нажимаем кнопку на форме "отменить":

```html
function cancelGanttTask() {
 if (taskId) {
  var task = gantt.getTask(taskId);
  if (task.$new) {
   delete task.$new;
   gantt.deleteTask(taskId);
  }
 }
 gantt.hideLightbox();
}
```

Вновь добавленный таск удаляется.
Далее нажимаем кнопку createGanttTaskOnclick() который должен добавить таск просто в конец списка без подчинения. А в результате такс снова подчиняется тому таску, который выбирался в начале.
В строке gantt.createTask(newTaskTemplate), что только не пробовал. Все равно используется последнее значение parentId.
Как в результате добавить таск без подчинения?

Answer (score 0):

Помогло в таком варианте:

```
function createGanttTaskOnclick() {
   var lightboxId = gantt.getState().lightbox;
   if (isEmpty(lightboxId)) {
      newTaskTemplate.parent = "0";
      gantt.createTask(newTaskTemplate);
   }}
```

Такой вариант: gantt.createTask(newTaskTemplate, "0"); 
Почему-то не работает.